# Solving systems of equations in R

Tags: r, symbolic-math

Solving an equation symbolically can be achieved in R using the Ryacas library.
For example

```
library(Ryacas)
yacas("Solve(x/(1+x) == a, x)")
```

gives

```
expression(list(x == a/(1 - a)))
```

Does anybody know how to (symbolically) solve a system of equations?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

Well, i use the excellent python library, ***sympy***,  for symbolic computation.

Using *sympy*, solving systems of equations straightforward:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x,y = symbols('x y')
>>> solve([Eq(x + 5*y, 2), Eq(-3*x + 6*y, 15)], [x, y])
{y: 1, x: -3}
```

So that's how to solve a system of equations using symbolic algebra, except through a python package.

The good news is that there's an R port to sympy, called ***rsympy***, which is available on CRAN, or Google Code, [here](http://code.google.com/p/rsympy/).

I have never used rsympy, other than downloading/installing it and working through a couple of the simplest examples in the rsympy Manual. I have used the original python library a lot during the past three years and i can recommend it highly.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
yacas( "OldSolve({a*x+y==0,x+z==0},{x,y})" )
```

Comment: do you have an idea about the following? If I run `yacas( "OldSolve({x+5*y==2,-3*x+6*y==15},{x,y})" )` then I get `{{x==2-5*y,y==1}};` which is fine, but I do not know why *x* was not computed to get -3 at the end. Is it possible to make R compute exact results?

Comment: I don't have a device with Yacas installed with me at the moment to test my solution, but after looking at the docs I would have tried: `yacas( "OldSolve({a*x+y==0,x+z==0}, x)" )`