# Solve simultaneous equations in R with variables

Tags: r, solver, differential-equations, equation-solving, simultaneous

I need to solve a system of four equations and solve for (Alg,Blg,C,D)..the others are simply variables.

```
dAlg = (ab*D + a1*f1*D*Alg*Blg + a2*f2*D*Alg*C)/e1 - m1*Alg;
dBlg = (f11*D*Blg)/eB - f1*Alg*Blg - mp*Blg;
dC = (f22*D*C)/eC - f2*Alg*C - mp*C;
dD = (f*R/(h + R)) - r*D - ab*D - a1*f1*D*Alg*Blg - f11*D*Blg - 
   a2*f2*D*Alg*C-f22*D*C;
```

So I want to solve { dAlg = 0, dBlg =0, dC = 0, dD = 0 } and then find out all possible combinations of solutions.

I am not sure how to do this on R using the solve package (as the [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145694/solving-simultaneous-equations-with-r) that I found seem for more trivial equations)..but when I do use another package I get the following answer. I want to achieve the same in R

```
    {{Alg -> ((eC f11 - eB f22) mp)/(-eC f11 f2 + eB f1 f22), 
  Blg -> -((
    eC f f11 f2 R - eB f f1 f22 R + 
     e1 (eC f11 - eB f22) m1 mp (h + R) + 
     eB eC (f1 - f2) mp r (h + R))/(eB eC f11 (f1 - f2) mp (h + R))), 
  C -> (ab eB eC f11 (f1 - f2) (-eC f11 f2 + eB f1 f22) (h + 
         R) + (eC f11 - 
         eB f22) (e1 m1 (eB f1 f22 (-f11 + a1 mp) + 
            eC f11 (f11 f2 - a1 f1 mp)) (h + R) + 
         a1 f1 (-eC f f11 f2 R + eB f f1 f22 R - 
            eB eC (f1 - f2) mp r (h + R))))/(a2 eB eC f11 (f1 - 
        f2) f2 (-eC f11 + eB f22) mp (h + R)), 
  D -> (eB eC (f1 - f2) mp)/(-eC f11 f2 + eB f1 f22)}, {Alg -> (
   ab f R)/(e1 m1 (ab + r) (h + R)), Blg -> 0, C -> 0, 
  D -> (f R)/((ab + r) (h + R))}, {Alg -> (
   f f22 R - eC mp r (h + R))/((e1 f22 m1 + eC f2 r) (h + R)), 
  Blg -> 0, 
  C -> ((e1 f22 m1 + eC f2 r) (h + 
      R) (ab eC (f f2 R + e1 m1 mp (h + R)) + 
      e1 m1 (-f f22 R + eC mp r (h + R))))/(
   a2 eC f2 (f f2 R + e1 m1 mp (h + R)) (-f f22 R + eC mp r (h + R))),
   D -> (eC (f f2 R + e1 m1 mp (h + R)))/((e1 f22 m1 + eC f2 r) (h + 
      R))}, {Alg -> (1/(
   2 a1 eB f1 (e1 f11 m1 + eB f1 r) (h + R)))(a1 eB f f1 f11 R - 
     e1 eB f11^2 m1 (h + R) + 
     eB^2 f1 (ab f11 - a1 mp r) (h + 
        R) + \[Sqrt](eB^2 (-4 a1 f11 mp (e1 f11 m1 + eB f1 r) (h + 
             R) (a1 f f1 R - 
             e1 m1 (f11 - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab eB f1 f11 (h + R) - 
            e1 f11 m1 (f11 - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
            a1 f1 (f f11 R + eB mp r (h + R)))^2))), 
  Blg -> -((-eB f11 (a1 f^2 f1^2 R^2 - 
           e1 f f1 m1 (f11 - a1 mp) R (h + R) + 
           e1^2 f11 m1^2 mp (h + R)^2) - 
        eB^2 f1 (h + R) (ab f11 (f f1 R + e1 m1 mp (h + R)) + 
           mp r (-a1 f f1 R + e1 m1 (2 f11 - a1 mp) (h + R))) + 
        e1 h m1 mp \[Sqrt](eB^2 (-4 a1 f11 mp (e1 f11 m1 + 
                 eB f1 r) (h + R) (a1 f f1 R - 
                 e1 m1 (f11 - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab eB f1 f11 (h + 
                   R) - e1 f11 m1 (f11 - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
                a1 f1 (f f11 R + eB mp r (h + R)))^2)) + 
        f f1 R \[Sqrt](eB^2 (-4 a1 f11 mp (e1 f11 m1 + eB f1 r) (h + 
                 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
                 e1 m1 (f11 - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab eB f1 f11 (h + 
                   R) - e1 f11 m1 (f11 - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
                a1 f1 (f f11 R + eB mp r (h + R)))^2)) + 
        e1 m1 mp R \[Sqrt](eB^2 (-4 a1 f11 mp (e1 f11 m1 + 
                 eB f1 r) (h + R) (a1 f f1 R - 
                 e1 m1 (f11 - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab eB f1 f11 (h + 
                   R) - e1 f11 m1 (f11 - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
                a1 f1 (f f11 R + 
                   eB mp r (h + R)))^2)))/(2 eB^2 f1 f11 mp (h + 
          R) (a1 f f1 R - e1 m1 (f11 - a1 mp) (h + R)))), C -> 0, 
  D -> (1/(2 a1 f11 (e1 f11 m1 + eB f1 r) (h + 
      R)))(eB^2 f1 (ab f11 + a1 mp r) (h + R) + 
     eB f11 (a1 f f1 R - 
        e1 m1 (f11 - 2 a1 mp) (h + 
           R)) + \[Sqrt](eB^2 (-4 a1 f11 mp (e1 f11 m1 + eB f1 r) (h +
              R) (a1 f f1 R - 
             e1 m1 (f11 - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab eB f1 f11 (h + R) - 
            e1 f11 m1 (f11 - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
            a1 f1 (f f11 R + eB mp r (h + R)))^2)))}, {Alg -> (1/(
   2 a1 eB f1 (e1 f11 m1 + eB f1 r) (h + R)))(a1 eB f f1 f11 R - 
     e1 eB f11^2 m1 (h + R) + 
     eB^2 f1 (ab f11 - a1 mp r) (h + 
        R) - \[Sqrt](eB^2 (-4 a1 f11 mp (e1 f11 m1 + eB f1 r) (h + 
             R) (a1 f f1 R - 
             e1 m1 (f11 - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab eB f1 f11 (h + R) - 
            e1 f11 m1 (f11 - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
            a1 f1 (f f11 R + eB mp r (h + R)))^2))), 
  Blg -> (eB f11 (a1 f^2 f1^2 R^2 - 
         e1 f f1 m1 (f11 - a1 mp) R (h + R) + 
         e1^2 f11 m1^2 mp (h + R)^2) + 
      eB^2 f1 (h + R) (ab f11 (f f1 R + e1 m1 mp (h + R)) + 
         mp r (-a1 f f1 R + e1 m1 (2 f11 - a1 mp) (h + R))) + 
      e1 h m1 mp \[Sqrt](eB^2 (-4 a1 f11 mp (e1 f11 m1 + eB f1 r) (h +
                R) (a1 f f1 R - 
               e1 m1 (f11 - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab eB f1 f11 (h + R) - 
              e1 f11 m1 (f11 - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
              a1 f1 (f f11 R + eB mp r (h + R)))^2)) + 
      f f1 R \[Sqrt](eB^2 (-4 a1 f11 mp (e1 f11 m1 + eB f1 r) (h + 
               R) (a1 f f1 R - 
               e1 m1 (f11 - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab eB f1 f11 (h + R) - 
              e1 f11 m1 (f11 - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
              a1 f1 (f f11 R + eB mp r (h + R)))^2)) + 
      e1 m1 mp R \[Sqrt](eB^2 (-4 a1 f11 mp (e1 f11 m1 + eB f1 r) (h +
                R) (a1 f f1 R - 
               e1 m1 (f11 - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab eB f1 f11 (h + R) - 
              e1 f11 m1 (f11 - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
              a1 f1 (f f11 R + 
                 eB mp r (h + R)))^2)))/(2 eB^2 f1 f11 mp (h + 
        R) (a1 f f1 R - e1 m1 (f11 - a1 mp) (h + R))), C -> 0, 
  D -> (1/(2 a1 f11 (e1 f11 m1 + eB f1 r) (h + 
      R)))(eB^2 f1 (ab f11 + a1 mp r) (h + R) + 
     eB f11 (a1 f f1 R - 
        e1 m1 (f11 - 2 a1 mp) (h + 
           R)) - \[Sqrt](eB^2 (-4 a1 f11 mp (e1 f11 m1 + eB f1 r) (h +
              R) (a1 f f1 R - 
             e1 m1 (f11 - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab eB f1 f11 (h + R) - 
            e1 f11 m1 (f11 - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
            a1 f1 (f f11 R + eB mp r (h + R)))^2)))}}
```

Comment: Possibly you could use `Ryacas` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075983/solving-systems-of-equations-in-r), but after 5 minutes `OldSolve` still wasn't done when I tried your system...